# Passing PHP array to Javascript array using implode(), join() or json_encode()

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress plugin and I need to pass PHP array to Javascript array. I have tried using join(), implode() and even Json_encode. But, the wordpress is not displaying any value.

When using join(), I used the code:

```
<?php
$php1 = array(1,2,3);

?>
<script language='Javascript'>
var lat = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $php1); ?>"];
document.write(lat[1]);
</script>
```

If used on localhost(without wordpress), the above code provides a valid output. But, somehow, its not working on Wordpress. The "apache error log" show this message:

PHP Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in \wp-content\plugins\Animation\animation.php on line 129, referer: http://localhost/Website/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=js

Same is the case with implode(). Server error log shows same above warning for implode().

Then I tried for json_encode using the code below:

```
var lat = <?php echo json_encode($php1); ?>;
```

But the no value is returned.

Edit: Code I used for JSON:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: PHPToJavascript
*/
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);            //array to pass

add_action('admin_menu','admin_jav');

function admin_jav(){
add_submenu_page('options-general.php','Javarray','Javarray','manage_options','javarray',jav_handler);
}

function jav_handler(){
echo 'Into handler';

?>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = 'Javascript'><!--
var sm=<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;      //using Json  

document.write(sm[1]);                       //doesnt display any output!!!

</SCRIPT>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please guide me through this. I appreciate any help. It would be great if you help me in passing this PHP array to javascript array.

Comment: You mean that if you write `alert(<?php echo json_encode($php1) ?>);`, nothing happens? Also note that the `language` attribute is deprecated, prefer using `type="text/javascript"` instead.

Comment: Well, I am using `document.write()` instead of `alert()`. But, I just want to pass contents of array `$php1` to array `lat` and then display first element of `lat`. I used `var lat = <?php echo json_encode($php1); ?>; document.write(lat[1]);` and nothing happens.

Comment: Try var <?php echo 'var lat = ' . json_encode($php1) . ';'; ?>; Otherwise I think you will have do var lat = "<?php echo json_encode($php1); ?>"; and then convert the string into json

Comment: @solartic, what? JSON *is* JavaScript and your first sentence has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: @Alex, then your problem is not the PHP, but rather the JavaScript. Is the `script` tag inside the `body` tag?

Comment: @Radu Yes JSON is Javascript. Javascript object notation.

Comment: @solartic... Therefore you don't need to "convert the string into json". The string returned by `json_encode` *is* JSON.

Comment: The php function will return a string, and not a javascript object. Therefore you would first have to collect the string and then parse to  javascript. And model javascript provides JSON.method to do so.

Comment: @solartic, `json_encode()` will return the string "`[1,2,3]`". That will make the HTML `<script>var lat = [1,2,3]; ...</script>`. That will cause the browser to read and interpret that, which in turn *will* create a `lat` JavaScript array with 3 elements. You don't need any `JSON` method for that, since `json_encode()` returns valid JSON.

Comment: The other simply print out the JavaScript code. Which is what I suggested initially.

Comment: @Radu...Yes, I've used script inside body tag. Still not working.

Comment: @Radu Sounds logical, I don't remember that being the case though. I'll give it a try and see.

Comment: @solartic, that's the *purpose* of `json_encode()`...

Comment: @Alex, can you try a new, empty, PHP script, without anything other than `<html><body><script type="text/javascript">var lat = <?php echo json_encode(array(1, 2, 3)) ?>; document.write(lat[1]);</script></body></html>` and see what happens?

Comment: @Rudu ok you were right it works!

Comment: @Radu... The value is displayed correctly.. Then, why not working with `$php1` array??? Please help. Seems we are near to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$arr` variable is out of scope. If you want to use the global `$arr` variable, you need to modify your `jav_handler()` function to bring the variable into local scope:

```
function jav_handler(){
    global $arr;
    // ...
```

However, it's good practice to always avoid global variables when you can, so the preferred way of doing this is to change the function to take the array as an argument and pass it explicitly when calling the function:

```
function jav_handler($arr){
    // ...
}

jav_handler($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
var lat = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $php1); ?>"];
document.write(lat[1]);
```

**to:**

```
var lat = ["<?php echo join('", "', $php1); ?>"];
document.write(lat[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var lat = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $php1); ?>"];
```

I would try:

```
var lat = "<?php echo json_encode($php1); ?>";
```

Additionally, you may want to use a Browser that offers proper JS debugging. In chrome, you can use `console.log(lat);` to see exactly what lat holds